# React JS setTimeout gets executed multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, settimeout

Hi everyone I'm new to React JS and I got stuck into a problem that cant figure out what is the cause. So I'm trying to make a search field component that only trigger an API call after a user is done typing. What happened is that after the search is keyed in *setTimeout* gets executed multiple times. I'm afraid this would make multiple unnecessary api call. Would very much appriciae your help. Thank you!

**main.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <App />
)
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import fetchData from './utils/fetch'
import { WeatherModel } from './model/Weather'

function SearchField() {
  let timer = 0
  const [city, setCity] = useState('New York')

  const handleFetchWeather = async () => {
    const data: WeatherModel = await fetchData(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${WEATHER_API_KEY}&units=metric`)
    console.log(data)
  }

  const handleSetCity = (e) => {
    if(timer) clearTimeout(timer)
    setCity(e.target.value)
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(city)
      // handleFetchWeather()
    }, 2000)
  }

  return (
    <div className="search">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search city..." onChange={handleSetCity} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchField
```

Muliple console logs after search is keyed in
[image]

Comment: This is because every time input is change then the settimeout function is calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with the debounce solution, but also if you didn't know it, this code might be even simpler for you, so each time a component rerenders, the timer is set with 0 again, so in order to persist the value, imagine you need to put it in a state, just like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function SearchField() {
  const [city, setCity] = useState("New York");
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);

  const handleFetchWeather = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${WEATHER_API_KEY}&units=metric`
    );
    console.log(data);
  };

  const handleSetCity = (e) => {
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    setCity(e.target.value);
    setTimer(
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(city);
        // handleFetchWeather()
      }, 2000)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="search">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search city..."
        onChange={handleSetCity}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchField;
```

Now, every rerender, the component will remember the previous value of it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Debounce](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-throttle-debounce/):

Here's an example :

```cs
useEffect(() => {
    let debounce;
    
    if (debounce) {
        clearTimeout(debounce);
        debounce = null;
    }

    debounce = setTimeout(() => {
        // DO SOMETHING AFTER TIMEOUT ENDS
        setSearchEntry(searchValue);
    }, 1 * 1000);
    
}, [setSearchEntry, searchValue]);
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

The onChange event in the input field will be fired on each new character input, learn more [here](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/react-onchange-events-with-examples).

I think the best solution, in this case, is to add submit button that fires handleSetCity() and your onChange should set a state variable so it's easier to handle the data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).